# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: spring, maven, eclipse, spring-security

При попытке импорта так же выдает:
`The import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cannot be resolved`

Вот файл:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
//import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("user")
                .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("removal")
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.
        csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().permitAll()
                    //Доступ только для не зарегистрированных пользователей
                    .requestMatchers("/registration").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                    //Доступ только для пользователей с ролью Администратор
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()




                .anyRequest().permitAll())

                    //Настройка для входа в систему
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    //Перенарпавление на главную страницу после успешного входа
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется, он устарел: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter